# Google Checkout - getting only first order-state-change-notification

Tags: php, payment-gateway, payment, google-checkout, android-pay

I have implemented GC response handler for my application.
Everything works fine when testing it in sandbox on dev server.
Log says that we get the following notifications, one by one:

> new-order-notification
>   order-state-change-notification(NEW,CHARGEABLE)
>   risk-information-notification
>   order-state-change-notification(PROCESSING,CHARGEABLE)
>   order-state-change-notification(PROCESSING,CHARGING)
>   order-state-change-notification(PROCESSING,CHARGED)
>   charge-amount-notification
>   order-state-change-notification(PROCESSING,CHARGED)

Everything seems OK, and when I am sure that order is **CHARGED**, I perform some action.
But on live server and live account there is another behavior.
The last thing I get is risk-information-notification.
Nothing more.
**Money are charged**, but I do not get **CHARGED** message and action is not executed.
Please, share your ideas about what is going up.
Did someone notice such behavior?
Regards, Bogdan.

Comment: Please make sure you did all the points mentioned here: https://developers.google.com/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_Basic_HTML_Sandbox#Launching_to_Production

Comment: @OMG Done, all code was written so that it is easy to switch from sandbox to live and back.

Comment: Anyone? Some more suggestions?

Comment: Clarify what you mean by "money is charged" - you mean order is charged?

Comment: ok - are your sandbox and production `integration settings` identical (version, notification filtering, etc)?

Comment: @EdSF Yes, managed to check today. I cannot test on live server with dev credentials. But it does not seem to matter. Seems like there are some differences between sandbox and live Google checkout behavior, which are not described anywhere. Settings are same, API V2.0 + unsigned shopping cart support.

Comment: Anything in your **production** integration console (error messages)?